# Embed bing search into nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, bing-api

I wanna embed bing search into Nodejs, I read the document [a link](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&wdo=2&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04). However, the method is about php, I cannot find a tutorial about how to use bing search in nodejs.(I am a newbie, I am not familiar with php. I tried to convert php code into nodejs and I failed since there is much difference between these two)

suppose, I have the bing.ejs like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Bing Search Tester (Basic)</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Bing Search Tester (Basic)</h1>
  <form  method="POST" action="/bing">
   <label for="service_op">Service Operation</label><br/>
   <input name="service_op" type="radio" value="Web" CHECKED /> Web
   <input name="service_op" type="radio" value="Image" /> Image
   <br/>
   <label for="query">Query</label><br/>
   <input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="" /><br /><br />
   <input name="bt_search" type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
  <h2>Results</h1>
 {RESULTS}
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I write code in

```
app.post('/bing', function(req, res) {
    var service_op = req.body.service_op;
    var query = req.body.query;
            //something to add...
});
```

What should I write next? or can anyone give me a template? thx!

Comment: Use [`bing-api`](https://github.com/VarioLabs/bing-api.js)?

Comment: @robertklep are u sure we can use bing-api, because you know bing search has changed, and they use Primary Account Key instead of AppID. Does this npm still work?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. Perhaps there's another Bing module available in the [npm repository](http://npmjs.org/) that's more recent.

Comment: @robertklep well, I do not think so. I check all the npms, it seems they all out-dated..Do u know how to embed bing search into nodejs?

Comment: The documents seem to just perform HTTP requests; a good module for performing those is [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

Comment: @robertklep can you give me more hints? Because I am newbie, not very familiar with this..Or can u write a template ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
// this somewhere at the top of your code:
var acctKey = 'YourAPIKey';
var rootUri = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search';
var auth    = new Buffer([ acctKey, acctKey ].join(':')).toString('base64');
var request = require('request').defaults({
  headers : {
    'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + auth
  }
});

// here's how to perform a query:
app.post('/bing', function(req, res) {
  var service_op  = req.body.service_op;
  var query       = req.body.query;
  request.get({
    url : rootUri + '/' + service_op,
    qs  : {
      $format : 'json',
      Query   : "'" + query + "'", // the single quotes are required!
    }
  }, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err)
      return res.send(500, err.message);
    if (response.statusCode !== 200)
      return res.send(500, response.body);
    var results = JSON.parse(response.body);
    res.send(results.d.results);
  });
});
```

This code uses the [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, so install that first:

```
$ npm install request
```

Comment: it says an error occur.. When uses request. I just need to do this `var request = require('request');`right?

Comment: can u register 5,000 transactions/month? Or if u really need, I can send you the key..U know I have been working this problem two days.. Still cannot finish this job..really need help!

Comment: can u tell me your email or something? really need help! thx!

Comment: @CSnerd my e-mail address is on my [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep), if you send me your Bing credentials I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bing-api) that encapsulates the requests, so you can use it
like:

```
var Bing = require('node-bing-api')({ accKey: "your-account-key" });

Bing.web(req.body.query, function(error, res, body){
    console.log(body);
  },
  {
    top: 50,
    market: 'en-US' 
  });
```

It works with the Azure version. You only have to replace your account key.